# Can't Connect to my rds instance through datagrip

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, datagrip

I am deploying an rds db instance with aws cdk

I've tried so many different things, like adding a security group which allows all incoming traffic to the sub-net my RDS instance lives on, set publicly accessible to true, checked my firewall settings etc.  I've been able to connect to a simple RDS instance with DataGrip that I made through the console but for some reason deploying with AWS SDK I just can't connect.

Am I missing something here?

Connecting to RDS but it doesn't work

Comment: You seem to have covered the main things (Security Group, Publicly accessible). Also confirm that the instances was launched in a **public subnet** (defined as having a Route Table that points to an Internet Gateway). The fact that it was launched via CDK wouldn't cause the problem. Rather, something in the settings would be different. Compare the settings against the RDS instance you launched manually and try to Spot the Difference!

Comment: Please contact DataGrip support via 'Help | Contact Support', and provide screenshots of your data source connection configuration ('General' tab, 'SSH\SSL' tab if SSH is used) and a screenshot or text of the error message. Also IDE logs for analysis (entire archive): 'Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data'. Logs can be attached to the ticket or uploaded privately to https://uploads.jetbrains.com

Comment: @like9orphanz, what's the error message?